# Putty SSH, refused connection by guest mininet machine

Tags: virtualbox, ssh

I followed the main VM installation notes on the Mininet website, and the VM works totally fine. But When I tried to SSH into the VM, at first it timedout the connection. Then after searching on the internet, I followed [this](http://christophermaier.name/blog/2010/09/01/host-only-networking-with-virtualbox) guide, to add a new host-only adapter. But now the SSH displays a **refused connection**  message. I don't know where did I go wrong. I would be glad if anyone could help me.

Comment: firewall? Ping?

Comment: The ping is working fine and i get the reply from the guest.

Comment: And do you have firewall on the guest rejecting SSH connections?

Comment: Actually i'm not sure about it. Any pointers on how should I check that?

Comment: I actually disabled the firewall on my guest machine via `sudo ufw disable` . but still I can't ssh into the machine, and prompts the same refusal error.